# Typeorm: Custom JoinTable with additional attribute

Tags: typescript, sqlite, typeorm, nest

Hi I am working on my firt nestJS app (SqLite) which should also implement simple chat functionality for users that are friends. At the beginning I had a simple ManyToMany relationship between users that were friends, however, when I wanted to implement the chat entity I felt liek it would be a good idea to replace the auto-generated user table with a table that holds two friends and the messages they sent to each other.

This is my current code:
FriendsEntity:

```
@Entity()
export class FriendsEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
    @ManyToMany(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.friendships)
    users: UserEntity[]
    //save messages for chat here
    @OneToMany(() => MessageEntity,
        (message) => message.chat, {
            cascade:true
        })
    messages: MessageEntity[]

}
```

UserEntity:

```
import {Entity, Column, JoinTable, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToMany, JoinColumn, Unique, OneToMany} from 'typeorm'
import { DuelEntity } from "../duel/duel.entity";
import {Exclude} from "class-transformer";
import { FriendrequestEntity} from "../requests/friendrequest.entity";
import {DuelrequestEntity} from "../requests/duelrequest.entity";
import {MessageEntity} from "../chat/message.entity";
import {FriendsEntity} from "../friendlist/friends.entity";


@Entity()
@Unique(["username"])
@Unique(["email"])
export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id : number
    @Column({ name: "username" })
    username : string
    @Column({ name: "email" })
    email : string
    @Exclude() //exclude password from response body
    @Column()
    password : string

    @ManyToMany(() =>FriendsEntity, (friends) => friends.users)
    friendships: FriendsEntity[];

    @Column()
    role : string

    @OneToMany(() => MessageEntity,
        (message) => message.sender)
    sentMessages: MessageEntity[];

}
```

However, this doen't seem to work as I am getting the follwing error message:
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tablePath')
When trying to select all friends of a certain user.
Maybe my whole approach to this is wrong and I should change the structure of the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.